# MySQL - join in one query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

leads

```
|lead_id|name|
|      1|   a|
|      2|   b|
|      3|   c|
```

lead_phases

```
|phase_id|phase_lead_fk|phase_sort|phase_status|
|       1|            1|         1|           1|
|       2|            1|         2|           0|
|       3|            2|         3|           1|
|       4|            2|         1|           0|
|       5|            2|         2|           0|
|       6|            3|         1|           0|
|       7|            3|         2|           1|
```

I have to write one query which show joined table grouped by lead_id and the highest value of column phase_sort.

The result I would like to receive:

```
|lead_id|name|phase_id|phase_sort|phase_status|
|      1|   a|       2|         2|           0|
|      2|   b|       3|         3|           1|
|      3|   c|       7|         7|           1|
```

My query:

```
SELECT phase_id,phase_lead_fk,phase_sort,phase_status
FROM leads
LEFT JOIN lead_phases ON lead_id=phase_lead_fk
GROUP BY lead_id
```

Comment: That GROUP BY is invalid, wont even execute on newer MySQL versions (unless in compatibility mode.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: You need a sub-query that uses GROUP BY to return each lead_id with its highest phase_sort. Join with that result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in two steps

```
select  phase_lead_fk, max(phase_sort)
from    lead_phases
group by phase_lead_fk
```

this will return the hights sort value for each lead; then you can use this result as a filter by joining it with the two original tables

```
select  *
from    leads t1
join    lead_phases t2
on      t1.lead_id = t2.phase_lead_fk
join    (
            select  phase_lead_fk, max(phase_sort) max_phase_sort
            from    lead_phases
            group by phase_lead_fk
        ) t3
on      t2.phase_lead_fk = t3.phase_lead_fk and
        t2.phase_sort = t3.max_phase_sort
```